# using unique_ptr to manage Multidimensional pointer in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
int **p = new int*p[5]
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)p[i] = new int[6];
```

Now I want to use unique_ptr to replace p or manage p, How ?
I try to do like this:

```
unique_ptr<int [][6]> p(new int[5][6]);  
p[4][5] = 12;
cout<<p[4][5];
```

And it works. But I don't know why? The code "new int[5][6]" is not a valid c++ grammar.

I know the code below is a way to achieve my goal,but I want to know if there is a grace way to do it.

```
unique_ptr<int[]>p[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)p[i].reset(new int[6]);
```

Comment: I would suggest you use vector< vector<int> > for this purpose.

Comment: "The code "new int[5][6]" is not a valid c++ grammar." - yes it is. It's array-new, `new T[6]`, where the type is `int[5]`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour you mean that I can use it like that way ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I know vector is a good choice. I just want to figure out how to use smart points like that

Comment: `new int[5][6]` is valid C++. Your second way isn't.

Comment: you could use `unique_ptr< unique_ptr<int[]>[] >`, but as Abhushek Bansal suggested, `vector< vector<int> >` is a better option.

Comment: I want to get this screw out. I know a screwdriver is a good choice. I just want to figure out how to use a bycicle for that.